# FieldPath field names may not start with '$'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the following code

```js
if (typeof(searchTerm) == "string") {
  let posts = await Post.reusablePostQuery([{
    $match: {
      $text: {
        $search: searchTerm}
      }
    }, {
      $sort: {
        score: {
          $meta: "textScore"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

I'm getting the following error

> `FieldPath field names may not start with '$'`

Comment: You are trying aggregate method syntax without the `aggregate` keyword.

Comment: What is `Post` ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, But when I removed
below code and comma(,) before it worked for me

```js
{
   $sort: {
        score: {
          $meta: "textScore"
        }
      }
  }
```